# CakePHP dynamic dropdown menu changing pages error in controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

**cakePHP version 2.4.5** 
I have managed to create a dynamic dropdown menu from my database using element and pagesController.

In my **element** navigation.ctp

The Code below loops through the database via $events which comes from Layout default.ctp

```
foreach ($events as $event): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="/cake_sports/pages/events/<?php echo $event['Event']['id'] ?>"><?php echo
                        $event['Event']['description']; ?></a>

    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($event); ?>
```

In my **PagesController** display(): 
This will get items from the database and pass it to Layout default.ctp

```
$this->Event->unbindModel(array('hasMany'=>array('Player')));
$this->set('events', $this->Event->find('all'));
```

In my **Layout** *default.ctp* 
This will call navigation.ctp element with $events as paramater

```
<?php
  echo $this->element('navigation', $events);
?>
```

**PROBLEM:** When I navigate or go to other pages other than EventsController, I will get an error. The error is understandable since I know that it will not identify the `$this->set('events', $this->Event->find('all'));`. But I don't know how to make it global so that even after changing pages with different controller it will not mess up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it inside `AppController`

```
public $uses = array('Event');

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Event->unbindModel(array('hasMany'=>array('Player')));
    $this->set('events', $this->Event->find('all'));
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Do this only if you need it on all the pages.

Also, you can change

```
<a href="/cake_sports/pages/events/<?php echo $event['Event']['id'] ?>"><?php echo $event['Event']['description']; ?></a>
```

with

```
echo $this->Html->link($event['Event']['description'], array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'events', $event['Event']['id'] ));
```

Comment: I also did this: It gives me : `Call to a member function find() on a non-object` when i remove the unbindModel. And if not it will give me  `Call to a member function unbindModel() on a non-object`

Comment: are you sure you have `public $uses = array('Event')` ? Also, I added the `parent::beforefilter`

Comment: VERY cool, yeah i thought public $uses=array('Event') = App::uses(); So I putted `$uses=array('Event')` inside the class and works great now. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Controller :

<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js');

    public $components = array('Flash','RequestHandler');


    public $uses = array('User','State','City');

    public function getByCity() {
    $state_id = $this->request->data['User']['state_id'];

    $cities = $this->City->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('City.state_id' => $state_id),
    'recursive' => -1
    ));

    $this->set('cities',$cities);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }
    public function index() {
         if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $term = $this->request->query('term');
        $emails = $this->User->getEmails($term);
        $this->set(compact('emails'));
        $this->set('_serialize', 'emails');
        }
         if($this->request->is('post')){
             if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Successully save your information!!');
                $this->redirect('index');
             }
             else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to save your Information!!');
                $this->redirect('index');
             }
         }
        $states = $this->User->State->find('list');
        $cities = $this->User->City->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('states', 'cities'));         
    }
}

User Modal :

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';

    public function getEmails ($term = null) {
      if(!empty($term)) {
        $emails = $this->find('list', array(
          'fields' => array('User.email'),
          'conditions' => array(
            'email LIKE' => trim($term) . '%'
          )
        ));
        return $emails;
      }
      return false;
    }
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'State' => array(
            'className' => 'State',
            'foreignKey' => 'state_id'
        ),
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
        )        
    );
     //put your code here
     public $validate=array(
             'name'=>array(
             'rule'=>'notBlank',
             'required'=>true,
             'message'=>'Input your name'
             ),
             'email'=>array(
             'email'=>array(
             'rule'=>'email',
             'message'=>'Input a valid emial address'
             ),
             'email'=>array(
             'rule'=>'notBlank',
             'required'=>true,
             'message'=>'Input your email address'
             )
     ),

     );


}
?>

City Model :

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class City extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'City';
          public $hasMany = array(
          'User' => array(
              'className' => 'User',
              'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
           )
      );
}
?>

State Model :

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class State extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'State';

          public $hasMany = array(
          'User' => array(
              'className' => 'User',
              'foreignKey' => 'state_id'
           )
      );
   }

?>


index.js :

(function($) {
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/save/users/index.json"
  });
})(jQuery);


index.ctp :

<?php 

  //let's load jquery libs from google
  $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', array('inline' => false));
  $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js', array('inline' => false));
   //load file for this view to work on 'autocomplete' field
  $this->Html->script('View/Users/index', array('inline' => false));
?>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
 <legend>Add New User</legend>
 <?php
 echo $this->Form->input('name',array('required'=>'required'));
 echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
               'id' => 'autocomplete'));
 echo $this->Form->input('country',array('options'=>array(
 'bangladesh'=>'Bangladesh',
 'india'=>'India',
 'pakistan'=>'Pakistan' ,
 'usa'=>'USA',
 'uk'=>'UK',
 'canada'=>'Canada'
 )
 ));
  echo $this->Form->input('state_id');
  echo $this->Form->input('city_id');
  echo $this->Form->end('Save');
 ?>
</fieldset>

<?php
$this->Js->get('#UserStateId')->event('change', 
$this->Js->request(array(
'controller'=>'Users',
'action'=>'getByCity'
), array(
'update'=>'#UserCityId',
'async' => true,
'method' => 'post',
'dataExpression'=>true,
'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
'isForm' => true,
'inline' => true
))
))
);
?>

get_by_city.ctp :

Controller :

<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js');

    public $components = array('Flash','RequestHandler');


    public $uses = array('User','State','City');

    public function getByCity() {
    $state_id = $this->request->data['User']['state_id'];

    $cities = $this->City->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('City.state_id' => $state_id),
    'recursive' => -1
    ));

    $this->set('cities',$cities);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }
    public function index() {
         if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $term = $this->request->query('term');
        $emails = $this->User->getEmails($term);
        $this->set(compact('emails'));
        $this->set('_serialize', 'emails');
        }
         if($this->request->is('post')){
             if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Successully save your information!!');
                $this->redirect('index');
             }
             else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to save your Information!!');
                $this->redirect('index');
             }
         }
        $states = $this->User->State->find('list');
        $cities = $this->User->City->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('states', 'cities'));         
    }
}

User Modal :

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';

    public function getEmails ($term = null) {
      if(!empty($term)) {
        $emails = $this->find('list', array(
          'fields' => array('User.email'),
          'conditions' => array(
            'email LIKE' => trim($term) . '%'
          )
        ));
        return $emails;
      }
      return false;
    }
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'State' => array(
            'className' => 'State',
            'foreignKey' => 'state_id'
        ),
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
        )        
    );
     //put your code here
     public $validate=array(
             'name'=>array(
             'rule'=>'notBlank',
             'required'=>true,
             'message'=>'Input your name'
             ),
             'email'=>array(
             'email'=>array(
             'rule'=>'email',
             'message'=>'Input a valid emial address'
             ),
             'email'=>array(
             'rule'=>'notBlank',
             'required'=>true,
             'message'=>'Input your email address'
             )
     ),

     );


}
?>

City Model :

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class City extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'City';
          public $hasMany = array(
          'User' => array(
              'className' => 'User',
              'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
           )
      );
}
?>

State Model :

<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class State extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'State';

          public $hasMany = array(
          'User' => array(
              'className' => 'User',
              'foreignKey' => 'state_id'
           )
      );
   }

?>


index.js :

(function($) {
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/save/users/index.json"
  });
})(jQuery);


index.ctp :

<?php 

  //let's load jquery libs from google
  $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', array('inline' => false));
  $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js', array('inline' => false));
   //load file for this view to work on 'autocomplete' field
  $this->Html->script('View/Users/index', array('inline' => false));
?>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
 <legend>Add New User</legend>
 <?php
 echo $this->Form->input('name',array('required'=>'required'));
 echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
               'id' => 'autocomplete'));
 echo $this->Form->input('country',array('options'=>array(
 'bangladesh'=>'Bangladesh',
 'india'=>'India',
 'pakistan'=>'Pakistan' ,
 'usa'=>'USA',
 'uk'=>'UK',
 'canada'=>'Canada'
 )
 ));
  echo $this->Form->input('state_id');
  echo $this->Form->input('city_id');
  echo $this->Form->end('Save');
 ?>
</fieldset>

<?php
$this->Js->get('#UserStateId')->event('change', 
$this->Js->request(array(
'controller'=>'Users',
'action'=>'getByCity'
), array(
'update'=>'#UserCityId',
'async' => true,
'method' => 'post',
'dataExpression'=>true,
'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
'isForm' => true,
'inline' => true
))
))
);
?>

get_by_city.ctp :

<?php foreach ($cities as $key => $value): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```